# module export usage error in node

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, dbmigrate

I'm having `db.js` file which consist of

```
var mysql      = require('mysql2');
var mysqlModel = require('mysql-model');
    var appModel = mysqlModel.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'root',
      password : 'root',
      database : 'tabio',
    }); 

var User = appModel.extend({
    first: "table_first",
});
var Message = appModel.extend({
    second: "table_second",
});

module.exports = {
  first : first,
  second : second
};
```

I am requesting the `db.js` in another file `main.js` like

```
var connection = require('./db.js');
test = new connection.first({ 
    column1: 12, 
    column2: 34,  
});
test.save();
```

it successfully saves the recored. But how can i run `select`, `delete`, `update` query here.

while using `var test = connection.first.find(1);`, i get the error `TypeError: connection.User.find is not a function`. how to use the `select` & `update` query using `db-migrate`?

Answer (score 1):

```
test = new connection.first();
```

then you can use `test.query, test.find`.

> query Runs custom query
>
> Usage:
>
> movie.query(query); movie.query(query, callback); Parameters:
>
> string query: Your custom sql query to run function callback: returns
>   errors and results Example:
>
> movie.query("SELECT name FROM movies WHERE director = 'James Cameron'
>   ORDER BY year", function(err, rows, fields) {
>       // Do something... });